# Intuition about rank–nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, we have this formula:

$dim\, V = dim\, null\, T + dim\, range\, T$

where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to some other vector space.

From this formula, what can be said about $A$ and $B$? where

$A = V - null\,T$, and $B = range\, T - \{0\}$

I thought that there is a bijection between the two, but there isn't (at least, I cannot find one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object $V - \operatorname{null}(T)$ is problematic, since this is not a vector space, but I sort of see how you are attempting to match dimensions. If you meant quotient, then indeed you have the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem) in the case of vector spaces.

In the [Wikipedia page for the rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), they state the following.

> One can refine this statement [the rank-nullity theorem] ... to be a statement about an isomorphism of spaces, not just dimensions.

Indeed in the proof, they begin by taking a basis $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ for $\operatorname{null}(T)$ (where $m=\dim \text{null}(T)$), and then extend it to a basis $\{u_1,\ldots, u_m, w_1,\ldots, w_n\}$ for $V$ (where $n = \dim \operatorname{range}(T)$). They then proceed to show that $\{T w_1,\ldots, T w_n\}$ is a basis for $\operatorname{range}(T)$, which gives the isomorphism that you were trying to find, between $\operatorname{span}(w_1,\ldots, w_n)$ and $\operatorname{range}(T)$.

Comment: After asking this question, I thought, when I was editing this question, I know what I want to ask, but I didn't write that down (because I don't know how to express it), and worried, will the viewers actually know what I want to ask? then I saw you said "see how you are attempting to match dimensions", it feels really good to have someone understand what you didn't say, thanks :)