# Basis of Ker + Basis of Rng = Basis V for Linear map L:V->W.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking at a lemma stating: Basis of Ker + Basis of Rng is the Basis of V if the inverse of Basis Rng exists. I looked at the proofs but I have the following questions:

1. Is there always basis from Ker? If I understand correctly, since Ker is a subset of V for linear map L:V->W so Ker might include the basis (since V is a vector space so it has basis) but I don't think those basis can always be the elements of Ker.
2. What is the geometrical meaning of basis of ker and rng? Looking at the proofs makes me think these are artificially set up so you can prove that the lemma is the case. For example, if Basis of Ker didn't exist, this lemma wouldn't hold?
3. Is there a geometrical way to understand this lemma and the Rank-Nullity theorem?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is incorrect for the reason you point out: the kernel is a subspace of $V$ while the range is a subspace of $W$. It does not make sense to talk about the sum of two subspaces of different vector spaces.

In [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1469902/43949) I outline the correspondence that I think your lemma is trying to make. Paraphrasing:

- Let $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ be a basis for the kernel (where $m$ is the dimension of the kernel). One can extend it to a basis $u_1 ,\ldots, u_m, w_1, \ldots, w_n$ for $V$ (where $m+n$ is the dimension of $V$).
- One can show that $Lw_1, \ldots, Lw_n$ (which are vectors in $W$, not $V$) form a basis for the range. So, the dimension of the range is $n$, and we obtain $\dim(\text{kernel}) + \dim(\text{range}) = \dim V$.

Details are in the [proof of the rank-nullity theorem from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for answering but is there a basis for the kernel always?

Comment: @Mardia If the kernel has dimension $\ge 1$ there always exists a basis. If the kernel has dimension zero, then you can start with a basis $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ for $V$ and show that $Lw_1, \ldots, L w_n$ is a basis for $W$.

Comment: I thought the Kernel was not a subspace because sum of elements in Kernel is not always in Kernel. I looked up and kernel is a subspace but its because transformations of elements of kernels are inside the kernel. Why is this??

Comment: @Mardia Kernels of linear transformations are always subspaces. If $u,v \in \ker(L)$ then $au+bv \in \ker(L)$ for any scalars $a,b$ becuase $L(au+bv) = a L(u) + b L(v) = 0 + 0 = 0$.